# Fetch data using ajax with async function

Tags: javascript, ajax, async-await

In the first example, I fetch data using `ajax` using `XMLHttpRequest` and it works fine

**example 1**

```
let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open(
    "GET",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/global-temperature.json"
);

let res = {};
req.onload = () => {
    res = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
};

req.send();

window.onload = _ => {
    console.log(res);
};
```

but i want to use the `async` function to save and minimize my code in single `function`
and here it is what i try

**example 2**

```
async function res() {
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open(
        "GET",
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/global-temperature.json"
    );

    let res = {};
    req.onload = () => {
        res = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    };

    req.send();
    return await res;
}

window.onload = _ => {
    console.log(res());
};
```

but it `log` in the `console` every time

```
Promise {<pending>}
```

Comment: You are awaiting `res` variable which is an empty object.

Comment: but i try to get its value from this part  `req.onload = () => {
        res = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    };`

Comment: Or more simply put `res().then(response => { console.log(response) }).catch(() => { alert("bad stuff"); })`

Comment: @BRO_THOM it print empty object

Comment: My bad, I thought I saw you using `Fetch` in the second snippet, but you're still using an `XMLHttpRequest` - you need to put your code within the `req.onload` function, because `onload` is the code that is executed after your request has been completed.

Comment: did you mean like that `req.onload = async () => {
  let res = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
  req.send();
  return await res;
 };` ?

Answer (score 1):

To use [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function you have to return the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

You could use the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) function as well it's a more modern way to fetching data.

Example:

```
const httpRequest = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://example.com/movies.json');
        return await response.json();
    } catch(e) {
        console.err(e);
    }
}
```

To solve your problem try to use so:

```
function request() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        req.open(
            "GET",
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/global-temperature.json"
        );

        req.onload = () => {
            resolve(JSON.parse(req.responseText));
        };

        req.send();
    })
}

function res() {
    request().then(data => console.log(data));
}

window.onload = _ => {
    console.log(res());
};
```

Comment: it get `Promise {<pending>}` :(

Comment: it getting `Promise {<pending>}` after edit to `fetch` to :(

Answer (score 0):

You are awaiting `res` variable which is an empty object. Try to await the Promise.
Example:

```
await req
return res
```

If that doesn't work try `.then()`